# Creating a bit mask with BigInts

Tags: python, bitmask

Is there a more efficient way of performing the following calculation? It works fine, but something tells me that `x &= (1 << 8) - 1 ^ 1 << 3` can be written to avoid some calculations and increase speed.

```
def unset_mask(width, index):
    return (1 << width) - 1 ^ 1 << index

x = 0b11111111
x &= unset_mask(8, 3)
assert x == 0b11110111
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to state the `width`. Bigints behave the right way when you do this:

```
>>> bin(255 & ~(1 << 3))
'0b11110111'
>>> bin(65535 & ~(1 << 3))
'0b1111111111110111'
>>> bin(75557863725914323419135 & ~(1 << 3))
'0b1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111'
```

It's because negative numbers have an ["infinite" string of ones preceding them](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). So when you complement a positive number (which starts with an "infinte" string of zeros), you get a negative number (`-(x + 1)` to be exact). Just don't trust the `bin` representation of negative numbers; it doesn't reflect the actual bits in memory.

So you would rewrite `unset_mask` like so:

```
def unset_mask(index):
    return ~(1 << index)

x = 0b11111111
x &= unset_mask(3)
print x == 0b11110111  # prints True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was a very thorough answer and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This will unset the bit:

```
x ^= 1 << 3 & x
```

In a function:

```
def unset_bit(x, n):
    return 1 << n & x ^ x
```

Comment: I cannot get it shorter than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to clear a bit in `x`:

```
x &= ~(1 << index)
```